# System.Servicemodel exception or StackOverflow exception while calling R code from C#

Tags: c#, r, garbage-collection, thread-safety, r.net

Tried Garbage collection and all kind of suggestions by R.net but no use.
I am getting System.Servicemodel exception or StackOverflow exception while trying to evaluate R code from C# using R.Net. What could be the best threadsafe way to call R.net methods from C#?

[image: Stack Overflow Exetion Screenshot link]